# Cannot use ps3joy with turtlesim (can't locate node [ps3_joy_node])

Tags: ros, turtlesim, ps3joy

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi everyone,

I am new to ROS. I was following the on using a ps3 controller to operate turtlesim but unfortunately I have encountered the following error after I use "roslaunch learning_ps3joy turtle_ps3joy.launch":

ERROR: cannot launch node of type [ps3joy/ps3_joy_node]: can't locate node [ps3_joy_node] in package [ps3joy]

I can see the turtlesim window with its turtle in it. I completed the tutorial to configure a ps3 controller and I was able to see it work with no errors.

Any ideas on why this is happening?

Edit 1:

I have a feeling the problem is in the launch file when executing the ps3joy node. Here is the code as it is shown in the tutorial:

Edit 2:
One thing that I have noticed is when I run `roscd joy` or `roscd ps3joy` the directory lies in /opt/ros/groovy/share/joy and /opt/ros/groovy/share/ps3joy. I have found the joy_node file in /opt/ros/groovy/lib/joy and the ps3joy_node.py in /opt/ros/groovy/lib/ps3joy directories.

Under the /opt/ros/groovy/share/joy directory all I see are:
cmake  migration_rules  package.xml

And for /opt/ros/groovy/share/ps3joy
cmake  diagnostics.yaml  launch  package.xml

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/63003/cannot-use-ps3joy-with-turtlesim-(can%27t-locate-node-%5Bps3_joy_node%5D)/) by [Pedro_85](https://answers.ros.org/users/4925/pedro_85/) on ROS Answers with karma: 182 on 2013-05-17

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [felix k](https://answers.ros.org/users/606/felix-k/) on 2013-05-22**:
Which ROS version are you using?

**Comment by [Pedro_85](https://answers.ros.org/users/4925/pedro_85/) on 2013-05-22**:
Groovy, sorry for not including that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The [fuerte version of `ps3_joy_node`](https://github.com/ros-drivers/joystick_drivers/blob/fuerte/ps3joy/bin/ps3_joy_node) had already been a redirection to `joy_node` of package [joy](http://www.ros.org/wiki/joy), naming its own use deprecated.

Apparently this was fully removed with groovy.

Please edit every launch file and tutorial you see with a call to `joy_node` `ps3_joy_node` into `joy` `joy_node` so this antiquity gets eliminated.

---

Originally posted by [felix k](https://answers.ros.org/users/606/felix-k/) with karma: 1650 on 2013-05-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Pedro_85](https://answers.ros.org/users/4925/pedro_85/) on 2013-05-21**:
I have run rosmake ps3joy and it reported no errors. As I said before I was able to use the ps3joy package to receive information from my ps3 controller. I have a feeling that the problem lies in the launch file commands. I have pasted the code in the question.

**Comment by [Pedro_85](https://answers.ros.org/users/4925/pedro_85/) on 2013-05-22**:
It didn't work either. The result was similar but with joy instead of ps3joy. I have edited the question with more details I have found.

**Comment by [Pedro_85](https://answers.ros.org/users/4925/pedro_85/) on 2013-05-22**:
Now it's working. In addition to your suggestion, I modified the manifest file adding `sensor_msgs` to the dependencies. Then I ran `rosrun ps3joy ps3joy_node.py` and in a different terminal launched the learning_ps3joy. Thanks for your help.